# selectlistitem validation message not kick in once form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I don't understand why the validation not kicking in once I submit the form.

I have this VM.

```
public EditFooDetailVm {
  public int FooDetailIdVm { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<EditFooVm> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class EditFooVm {
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public int FooDropDownId { get; set; }
  public int Index { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FooDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller:

```
var foo = _db.Foos
             .Select((f, i) => new EditFooDetailVm {
                 FooDetailIdVm = f.FooDetailId,
                 Foos = f.Foos
                         .Select(fs => new EditFooVm {
                             FooId = fs.FooId,
                             Index = i,
                             FooDropDown = fs.FooDropDown.ToSelectList(fd => fd.Name, fd => fd.Id)
                           })
               })
```

In my view:

```
@Model.FooDetailIdVm
@foreach(var item in Model.Foos) {
  @Html.DropDownList("Foos[" + item.Index + "].FooDropDownId", item.FooDropDown, "Please select")
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Foos[@item.Index].FooDropDownId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
}
```

I've already included in the page the validationjs but once I submit the form even if I didn't select any in the dropdown, the validation does not show up in the client side. I even result myself to manually create the markup when rendering the validation tag. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `foreach` loop in this way will not give correct 2-way binding to your model. You typically need either a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate`, but in the case of `DropDownList()` used in a collection, you need an `EditorTemplate`. Remove the `Index` property and change `FooDropDown` to typeof `SelectList`

```
public class EditFooVm {
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a foo")]
  public int FooDropDownId { get; set; }
  public SelectList FooDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
var foo = _db.Foos.Select(f => new EditFooDetailVm
{
  FooDetailIdVm = f.FooDetailId,
  Foos = f.Foos.Select(fs => new EditFooVm
  {
    FooId = fs.FooId,
    // Add FooDropDownId = ?? if you want to preselect an option
    FooDropDown = new SelectList(fs.FooDropDown, "Id", "Name")
  })
})
```

and create a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `EditFooVm`

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditFooVm.cshtml

```
@model EditFooVm
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FooDropDownId, Model.FooDropDown, "Please select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FooDropDownId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FooId) // ??
```

then in the main view

```
@Model.FooDetailIdVm
@using(Html.BeginFor())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FooDetailIdVm) // ??
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foos)
  ...
}
```

The `Html.EditorFor()` helper will correctly render your collection and give you 2-way binding.

Side notes: It's not clear, but if your query is generating identical select lists for each dropdown, then this is not efficient and you should be generating one select list (and assigning it to a property in the `EditFooDetailVm`). If that the case, you can then pass that select list to the `EditorTemplate` using additional view data

Main view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foos, new { FooList = Model.FooDropDown})
```

and in the template

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FooDropDownId, (SelectList)ViewData["FooList"], "Please select")
```